# Extracting all values between curly braces regex php (even press enter)

Tags: php, regex

I have a text:
`123123123{{abc}}123123`

My code to extract all values between curly braces

`preg_match_all('/{{(.*?)}}/', $text, $newText);`

It's OK, but if my text is:

`123123123{{
abc
}}123123`

It not work. How can I extract all values between curly braces with enter. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/s` for multiline :

```
preg_match_all('/{{(.*?)}}/s', $text, $newText);
```

`newText[1][0]` is `abc`.